# Does my function exist?

Tags: analysis

Is it possible to define a bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{R}^{-}\rightarrow[0,1)$ such that $f$ is continuously differentiable on its entire domain?

Comment: Please tell us what the strange ${\mathbb R}\setminus{\mathbb R}^-$ means:  ${\mathbb R}_{>0}$ or ${\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$ or something else?

Comment: It means the set of all nonnegative real numbers.  (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_subtraction#Relative_complement)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. For example, $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Answer (score 6):

If your domain is the reals greater than or equal to zero, $1-\exp(-x)$ seems to fill the bill.

Answer (score 3):

Let us consider $f\,:\,\left[0;+\infty\right[\rightarrow\left[0;1\right[$ defined as:
$$f = \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan$$